# System::Resources::MissingManifestResourceException after moving Form into new Namespace

Tags: c++, .net, resx

My problem is as follows:

I got a Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 project and the order to organize all classes in it in nested namespaces. Now I get System::Resources::MissingManifestResourceException on runtime, because the custom System::Windows::Forms has a assembly ressource and with the new namespace, the old Resx-file does not fit anymore. My problem is now, that I have no idea how to reconnect it to the Form-class.

The old code of the Form was like:

```
namespace OldNamespace{
  ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form{
      ...
  };
}
```

The new  code looks like:

```
namespace NewNamespace{
  namespace GUI{
      namespace MainWindow{
          ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form{
          ...
          };
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to adjust the filename of the created resource-file from the resx-file from

```
$(IntDir)\$(RootNamespace).$(InputName).resources
```

to

```
$(IntDir)\NewNamespace.GUI.MainWindow.MainForm.resources
```

But I am still getting System::Resources::MissingManifestResourceException on runtime.

What is my mistake?

Comment: I have found a solution.
I replaced 

    **_System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(ClassName::typeid));_**

by

**_System::Resources::ResourceManager^ resources = (gcnew System::Resources::ResourceManager("<Path to old .resources>",ClassName::typeid->Assembly));_**